# Wordpress enqueue_script does not work on tablet

Tags: wordpress, include, tablet

I am using a 3rd party plugin in my site and the wp_enqueue_script working well on every device except android tablet.
I have tested it with put an alert in the very first line of the file and it looks that the file isn't loaded at all.
My enqueue line is:

```
wp_enqueue_script($this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/ajax.js', array('jquery'), $this->version, true);
```

Any idea?

Additionally, you could test it here: 
http://7260.s.t4vps.eu/focus/ttest/

It will work on mobile or desktop, but on a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_enqueue_script` does not do any kind of browser or user agent detection.  What is suspect is happening is your tablet has a cached version of the ajax.js script stored locally from before you added the the alert. Try clearing the browser cache on your tablet and reload the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After I faced to this problem on a physical device, now I testing the site in an online tablet emulator, so the cache surely have deleted every time when I close that page.